# Is it possible to use "Passive Mode" with FtpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest, passive-mode

We have a process in place to upload a file nightly to a partner FTP site. They now require a passive connection and our uploads now fail. Is it possible for the .NET 4 FtpWebRequest to implement a passive connection instead of an active one? If so, can someone please provide an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the [`UsePassive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.usepassive.aspx) property to `true` on the FtpWebRequest.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add something to an old post - The FtpWebRequest.UsePassive property is True by default, so all requests should use passive already.

Answer (score 0):

Tried setting the `UsePassive` property on FtpWebRequest? See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.usepassive.aspx).